# After click on print button.Modal window is not closing/not only the modal it will stuck my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

below is my code.After printing the invoice modal window is not close.I have used below commented commands also.but it is not working.Is there any solution for this.I'm using meteor also

```
var printContents = document.getElementById('myInvoiceTablePrint').innerHTML;

var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
location.reload();
 // window.close();
console.log("print state");
 // $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
 // $('#myModal').modal('hide');
 // $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: have you tried $("#myModal").hide()?

Comment: yes.. but it is not working.

Comment: Why are you calling location.reload()? This will reload the document.

Comment: when it reloading it disapear.But that is not the best solution for this.I need a method to close the window without refreshing

Comment: Are you calling this from an actual popup window or a by modal do you mean an html element that is displayed on top of the document?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap modal here

Comment: You should probably use an external window or iframe to print instead of resetting the document body. This will most likely break the javascript event bindings on your page, causing all sorts of problems.

Comment: I think there should be a solution for closing this modal window.When I click on print using chrome it popup the print window .Then after click on the print button modal is not closing.I used modal.hide() method also..

Comment: If you comment everything out and just call $('#myModal').modal('hide'); does it work?

Comment: no.Wen click on print.the total code is die.not working.even cannot buttons are not woking

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier this is probably because you're resetting the body HTML. Try to find another method to print. Maybe css media queries.

Comment: I checked it again.This not only modal it will stuck all the buttons and other things.what is the reason for that.After refreshing it is works properly

Comment: @ThusilaBandara I think and I'm most probably correct in saying that the print dialog should not close before the document is sent to the printer and the printing finished feedback has been signaled - and therefore it doesn't close the control box before it has successfully printed the content of consideration; the printer might be out of paper; paper may jam during print; etc, etc, etc., and you'll be needing some UI to interact with it in order to be able to finish the job, which is in fact being sent to the Operating System.

Comment: do you have any idea to do that? @BekimBacaj